# Trace to Pin connection

Tags: circuit-design, layout, proteus

[image]I am having the issue of connecting my voltage regulator to the trace. The trace must be thick but the pins are too small.
What is the best solution? I am using proteus. Does making a solder Paste shape work?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A trace's resistance increases with length, and decreases with thickness. So the thickness is the more important the longer the trace is.

For a very short segment of the trace, the thickness does not change the total resistance by a noticeable amount. (Connections to through-hole pads are often deliberately made thinner to increase the thermal resistance; see [Does adding thermal relief on PCB increase electrical resistance?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/76402/29811))

So the shape of the connection does not really matter. The best solution is to not worry about it.

Comment: So i shouldn't worry about maybe this segment heats up and causes issues

Comment: Assuming a current of 1 A, you would need a trace width of less than 5 mil for a temperature increase of 50 °C.

Comment: okay,thank you CL!